# How to make a dropdown list using only innerText from Node list

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dom

```
  This is the line I am using to acquire my node list information. 
  document.querySelectorAll(".sorting_1")

  NodeList(48) [td.sorting_1, td.sorting_1, td.sorting_1, td.sorting_1,          
  td.sorting_1, td.sorting_1, td.sorting_1, td.sorting_1, td.sorting_1, 
  td.sorting_1, td.sorting_1, td.sorting_1, td.sorting_1, td.sorting_1, 
  td.sorting_1, td.sorting_1, td.sorting_1, td.sorting_1, td.sorting_1, 
  td.sorting_1, td.sorting_1, td.sorting_1, td.sorting_1, td.sorting_1,
  //...etc
```

Each item in this array has all the necessary attributes, I want to have it so I can one at a time only viewing the innerText and be able to select it .

Comment: You can't, `innerText` handles plain text only, it can't create elements.

Comment: So what would you suggest I do?

Comment: Please search some answers at SO, use "populate dropdown dynamically" as keywords.